# mySql Server Placement on AWS EC2 or RDS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-applications, forge

We are currently setting up AWS hosting for our Web Application.
This Laravel Web Application will have a Schema per company that registers, meaning it will have a large sized mySql server.

I have gone through the motions of setting up a VPC with EC2 instances and and RDS for this mySql server.
However we are currently looking at using Laravel Forge as a tool to host.
What Forge does differently is that it includes the mySql Server on the EC2 instance not on an RDS.

The question I have come to ask here is, what are the implications if any of having the mySql server on the EC2 instance rather then an RDS.

Would there be performance issues?
Is it better practice to have an RDS?
Or is Forges out the box way of packaging this all together on an EC2 server fine?

Comment: hey @ross summerell, did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

By running this on an EC2 instance you will taking more of the responsibility of managing the database, not just installation but also patching, backups, recovery. Harder to maintain functionality such as replication and HA will also be on you to implement and monitor.

By running on RDS AWS is going to take the heavy lifting of this and implement a best practice version of MySQL which offers the flexibility of allowing you to run a MySQL stack in the cloud without having to really think about the implementation details under the hood other than deciding do you want it to be HA and how many replicas do you want.

In saying this by using RDS you're also giving up the ability to run it however you want, you are limited to the versions of the database that RDS supports (although this is now quite soon after release). In addition not all plugins or extensions will be active so check this functionality before deciding.